# Challenges with HTML to PDF Conversion using Puppeteer in AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, lambda, puppeteer, serverless

***HTML TO PDF***

I am facing difficulties converting HTML to PDF using Puppeteer within an AWS Lambda environment configured with Node.js 16.

Although Puppeteer works reliably in local and server environments, its performance is inconsistent when deployed on AWS Lambda or serverless setups.

I have already explored solutions involving popular libraries like puppeteer and chrome-aws-lambda, but the issue persists.

I would appreciate any advice or recommendations to overcome this obstacle and achieve successful PDF generation in my serverless application.

**My Code**

```
const chromium = require('chrome-aws-lambda');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');

exports.handler = async (event) => {

  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      executablePath: await chromium.executablePath,
      args: chromium.args,
      headless: true,
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.setContent("<html><body><h5>Hello World!</h5></body></html>")

    const pdf = await page.pdf({
        format: "A4",
        path: "output.pdf"
    });

    return {statusCode: 200};
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return {statusCode: 500};
  }
};
```

**Coming This Error**

```
Failed to launch the browser process!\n/tmp/chromium: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory\n\n\nTROUBLESHOOTING:
```

Comment: `chrome-aws-lambda` [doesn't work on node 16](https://github.com/alixaxel/chrome-aws-lambda/issues/282). Try using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sparticuz/chromium instead

Comment: @apokryfos i have also used Nodejs14. but it is giving another error 

Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='

Comment: `??=` is not supported syntax in node 14. You must be using something that does not support node 14. I think just replacing the package with one that works is easier. It's much harder to set up transpilation to target a lower node version that includes node modules if you haven't done so already

Comment: @apokryfos I did't use this  `??=` anywhere in my code.

Comment: Please write a title that briefly describes the problem instead of just reiterating the tags.

Comment: I didn't say that you did, I am saying you might be using a library that is using that

Comment: @apokryfos i did with [@sparticuz/chromium](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sparticuz/chromium)

`const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-core");
const chromium = require("@sparticuz/chromium");
exports.handler = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: chromium.args,
    defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
    executablePath: await chromium.executablePath(),
    headless: chromium.headless,
  });
  
  await browser.close();
  
  return {statusCode: 200}; 
}`

giving error
`Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='`

Comment: That's because you still are on node 14. The point of changing the library is so you can use node 16+

Comment: @apokryfos i have used both node14 and 16

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I have had some luck with the `html-pdf` library -- depending upon how simple or complex your HTML page is, you could try something like this:

```
const HtmlPdf = require("html-pdf");
const html = `
<div>
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <hr>
  <p>this is only a test!</p>
</div>`;

HtmlPdf.create(html).toBuffer(function(err, buff) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(buff.toString());
});
```

Obviously it will not support as much of the HTML spec as a headless browser!
Good luck.